# Loading a file from dependency jar inside maven junit

Tags: java, maven-2, junit

I'm using maven 2.1.0 and have a project with multiple modules.
Example modules:

- spr-resources
- spr-common

spr-common has a dependency on spr-resources

spr-resources contains only files, no classes.

spr-common has a junit in which needs to load a file from spr-resources jar.

I used:

```
String fileName = getClass().getResource("/jaskeyfile.3DES").getFile();
is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
is.read(data);
```

And this works when I run the test in IntelliJ, but when I do mvn test, it fails with NullPointerException when I try to do read() on it.

Why is this happening? It should read a file from dependency just fine.

Also, pom.xml in spr-common has dependency on spr-resources (tried both with scope test and without it)

EDIT:
I tried also

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/jaskeyfile.3DES");
```

with no luck.

EDIT2:
The given file exists in the resulting jar, so I guess it should be accessible.

Comment: Mmm, that is strange. Have you tried a more simple way: `InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/java/pkg/with/your/file/filename.txt");`? Is the `spr-resources` dependecy really defined in the `pom.xml` file and not only in your IDE? The returned stream is `null` if the resource was not found on the CLASSPATH. Edit: Is the file really in the `spr-resources` in the `src/main/resources/java/pkg/with/your/file/filename.txt` directory?

Comment: If you run mvn test the test is run locally on this particular module. If you need the other module spr-resource you have to define it as test dependency otherwise you won't see this in your test cases.

Comment: I think that you see all the compile plus the test dependencies. So it should not be necessary to define it as a test dependency.

Comment: Old question but you never gave feedback on this!? :/

Answer (score 3):

**Check everything carefully**

Here's a list to work through:

1. The file `jaskeyfile.3DES` is located in `src/main/resources` within the spr-resources module
2. Your local repository contains the latest version of spr-resources-x.y.z-SNAPSHOT.jar (or you've released it/versioned it directly) and you've definitely used mvn clean install on it
3. The spr-common module is referencing the correct (named) version of spr-resources-x.y.z.jar (scope of compile will be seen on both test and compile classpaths)

If all the above are true then your `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/jaskeyfile.3DES")` invocation should work. I use this structure all the time in my projects so you're not asking for the moon or anything here.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue may be with the leading slash.  I think both of these should work:

- `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/jaskeyfile.3DES")`
- `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("jaskeyfile.3DES")`

`Class.getResourceAsStream()` takes a path relative to the class's package directory so it accepts the leading slash.

`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` takes an absolute path already so it doesn't accept the leading slash.

Comment: I tried both classloader, and get class getResourceAsStream, both with slash and without it